# Moving a string without using string instuctions in Assemply language programming 8086

Tags: assembly, x86-16, masm, dosbox

```
; Moving a string without using string instructions

ASSUME CS:CODE,DS:DATA,ES:EXTRA

DATA SEGMENT
    SOURCE  DB  11H,22H,33H,44H
DATA ENDS

EXTRA SEGMENT
    DEST    DB  ?
EXTRA ENDS

CODE SEGMENT

START:  MOV AX,DATA
        MOV DS,AX

        MOV AX,EXTRA
        MOV ES,AX

        MOV SI,OFFSET SOURCE
        MOV DI,OFFSET DEST
        MOV CX,0004H
        CLD

TRANSFER:   
        MOV AL,[SI]
        MOV [DI],AL
        INC SI
        INC DI 
        ;DEC CX
        LOOPNE TRANSFER

        MOV AH,4CH
        INT 21H

CODE ENDS
END START
```

I've tried the following variations of this program:

1. Used LOOP instead of LOOPNE
2. Used JNZ with DEC CX insead of Loop instructions

But I can't seem to transfer the data bytes. This is the output that while debugging in masm
[image: Unassembled code]
[image]

Comment: `loopne` is wrong. Use either `loop` or `dec cx` \ `jnz ...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the problem is the `MOV [DI],AL` instruction.

Without a segment prefix, it will assume that the address in DI is in the segment referenced by DS and you want to use the segment referenced by ES.

If I remember correctly, the syntax is `MOV ES:[DI],AL`

Comment: Or just simplify and put both buffers in the normal data segment so you don't need to mess around with ES at all.  Also note that `DEST    DB  ?` only reserves space for 1 byte, but the code copies 4 bytes.